# Combine two different tables

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables. One contains details of items, Second contains selling details and the third one contains the purchase details. I want to create query which displays a ledger type result. I have tried it but the following query is giving a warning like: Current selection does not contain a unique column.

The result table will also contain a column to identify from which table it is picking the values. Like, it will put `"P"` for purchase and `"S"` for sale.

I have searched everything but I am not able to find a solution in my case. Here is the query:

```
SELECT date,
       itemcode,
       qty,
       billno,
       price,
       "p" AS SP
FROM   purchase
WHERE  itemcode = 1007
UNION ALL
SELECT date,
       itemcode,
       qty,
       billno,
       rate,
       "s"
FROM   billing
WHERE  itemcode = 1007
ORDER  BY date ASC
```

Comment: Are you running this in PHPMyAdmin? because apparently this is not an SQL error but the application warning you, as PHPMyAdmin won't be able to make alterations without a unique column.

Comment: yes i am using PHP MyAdmin. All other things are working but I cannot not get to the logic like: if (SP == "P") {DO This} else {Do That}...

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date,
       itemcode,
       qty,
       billno,
       price,
       null AS rate,
       "p" AS SP
FROM   purchase
WHERE  itemcode = 1007
UNION ALL
SELECT date,
       itemcode,
       qty,
       billno,
       null AS price,
       rate,
       "s" AS SP
FROM   billing
WHERE  itemcode = 1007
ORDER  BY date ASC